# How to reconnect to google fit in android

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

Hi I've fitness app I have to connect google fit and share my fitness app data to google fit and I've to give option to disconnect.

I'm disconnecting by using below code.

```
Fitness.getConfigClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)).disableFit();
```

Once I disable unable to reconnect. if try upload data to google fit I'm getting below error.

> There was a problem reading the data.
>                                                                              com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4: The user must be signed in to make this API call.

Answer (score 1):

try this code before reconnect google fit api

```
  GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(HeartRateCountActivity.this, fitnessOptions);
                    // all fields of account are empty

                    if (!GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(account, fitnessOptions)) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Asking for permission");
                        GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                               HeartRateCountActivity. this,
                                001,
                                account,
                                fitnessOptions
                        );
                    } else { // this branch is executed which is weird
                        Log.i(TAG, "Already has permissions");
            //writer your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have [disconnected from Google Fit](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/disconnect), it revokes all granted OAuth permissions for your app and removes all recording subscriptions and sensor registrations made by your app. You should provide users with a Disconnect from Google Fit option in your app settings. Suggested action is to restart the app itself. The exception occurred when a call to Google Play services has failed. You need to [reconnect to the fitness service](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started#step_5_connect_to_the_fitness_service).